# Complicated Active Record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several classes:

```
class View < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :views, through: :articles
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :views
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :views
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :articles, through: :users
end
```

If I run:

```
Tag.joins(:articles).where(tag: tag, articles: { name: name }).first
```

it shows me first record in Tag, but if I run:

```
Tag.joins(:articles).where(tag: tag, articles: { name: name }).count
```

it shows me how many records in Article.

How to get an Article instead of Tag?

Thank you.

**ADDED**

Another one question - when I got all Articles that I need how can I sort them by views? Taking into account that there could be many View records per Article.

Comment: Please just write the classes out instead of writing text that describes them, real code is a lot easier to read than a description of said code and it lets people actually try the code for themselves. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And what is the actual desired output? If you want to get articles with a certain tag you would do it by: `Article.joins(:tags).where(tags: { id: tag.id })`. Since its a inner join it will only include rows with a match in the join table where `.includes` creates an outer join that includes everything anyways.

Comment: I updated my question. Desired output is to get all Articles with a certain name and certain tags.

Comment: `Article.joins(:tags).where(name: '100 ways Max is awesome', tags: { id: [tag1, tag2, tag3] })`

Comment: or  like this? ```Article.joins(:tags).where(name: '100 ways Max is awesome', tags: { id: Tags.where(tag: [tag1, tag2, tag3]).ids })```
it's kinda ugly))

Comment: If you already have a list of ids you don't need to make a scope. And `.ids` or `pluck(:ids)` should almost never be used. It forces AR to load the ids into an array where it can create a subquery instead. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Comment: I do not have ids. Also, it doesn't work - ```ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Articles' to association named 'tags'; perhaps you misspelled it?)```

Comment: You need to add an indirect assocation `has_many :tags, through: :user` or `joins(user: :tags)`. Although these assocations make zero sense. Why are the tags even associated with the user in the first place?

Comment: That actually works for me: ```has_many :tags, through: :user``` Thanks! Can you post it as a separate answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I even want to as its the wrong answer to the wrong question and I stand by my answer. You can answer it yourself it your want to.

Comment: It is a much more complicated DB. I simplified classes. Can you help me with the additional question? Forgot to add it, but provided View class...